# SSRS add line on page change

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a table in my report that has data like this :

```
+----------------+---------+---------+
| Lib1                               |      
+----------------+---------+---------+
| Data1          | Data11  | Data12  | 
| Data2          | Data21  | Data22  |   
| Data3          | Data31  | Data32  | 
| Data4          | Data41  | Data42  | 
| Data5          | Data51  | Data52  | 
+----------------+---------+---------+
| Lib2                               |
+----------------+---------+---------+
| Data6          | Data61  | Data62  | 
| Data7          | Data71  | Data72  |   
| Data8          | Data81  | Data82  | 
| Data9          | Data91  | Data92  |
```

I have 2 problems:

- First I'd like to have a closing line at the bottom of my table (in fact at the bottom of each group would be even better) but without having a line between each data line in the group. Example :

  ```
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Lib1                               |      
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Data1          | Data11  | Data12  | 
  | Data2          | Data21  | Data22  |   
  | Data3          | Data31  | Data32  | 
  | Data4          | Data41  | Data42  | 
  | Data5          | Data51  | Data52  | 
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Lib2                               |
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Data6          | Data61  | Data62  | 
  | Data7          | Data71  | Data72  |   
  | Data8          | Data81  | Data82  | 
  | Data9          | Data91  | Data92  | 
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  ```
- Second when I have a page break my data is like this :

  ```
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Lib1                               |      
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Data1          | Data11  | Data12  | 
  | Data2          | Data21  | Data22  |   
  | Data3          | Data31  | Data32  | 

  <-- page break -->

  | Data4          | Data41  | Data42  | 
  | Data5          | Data51  | Data52  | 
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Lib2                               |
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Data6          | Data61  | Data62  | 
  | Data7          | Data71  | Data72  |   
  | Data8          | Data81  | Data82  | 
  | Data9          | Data91  | Data92  |
  ```

  is it possible to add a closing line at the record if it is at the bottom of the page ? and add a line at the beginning on the next record of the page as on the example below:

  ```
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Lib1                               |      
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Data1          | Data11  | Data12  | 
  | Data2          | Data21  | Data22  |   
  | Data3          | Data31  | Data32  | 
  +----------------+---------+---------+

  <-- page break -->

  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Data4          | Data41  | Data42  | 
  | Data5          | Data51  | Data52  | 
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Lib2                               |
  +----------------+---------+---------+
  | Data6          | Data61  | Data62  | 
  | Data7          | Data71  | Data72  |   
  | Data8          | Data81  | Data82  | 
  | Data9          | Data91  | Data92  |
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple example I have a list of Numbers `Num` from 1 to 29.

I have created a table as shown.  The detail row `[Num]` has its borders set to None.  The tablix itself has its borders set to Solid, Blank.  The tablix also has the `OmitBorderOnPageBreak` property set to False.

[image]

Now when the data is exported to PDF the border is drawn across the bottom of the table on page 1 and across the top on Page 2

[image]

Hopefully this approach of setting the borders *of the tablix* and OmitBorderOnPageBreak will work for you